# How to exchange an refresh token for an access token .

Tags: oauth-2.0, thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture

I am trying to exchange an Access token  for an refresh token . 
I am sending client ID , secrete , grant type , scope in headers , URL query parameter and posting as Json over body , but I am receiving invalid client as response . 
Can you please me know how to exchange an refresh token for an access token . also please let me know if i have to make any changes in thinktecture OAuth server to enable this .

[image: POSTMAN screen grab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Content-Type of your request is "application/json", but the specification (RFC 6749) requires that the Content-Type of token requests be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".